# Why doesn't the following jquery code close the form after successful submission?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to close the form but the following code doesn't close the form after I clicks on submit button. Although I can see the alert message appearing which means control is goes in success: label but the form doesn't close what could be wrong ?? please help.

**html code**

```
<div id="signupmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog of sign up">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <form id="new_user_form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-content" data-method="post" id="modalform">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usr">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control input-sm" id="username">
            <label for="eml">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="emil" class="form-control input-sm" id="emailid">
            <label for="passwordd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-sm" id="password">
          </div role="Form group">
        </div role="modal-dialog">
        <!--Closing Of Sign Up Modal Page -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div role="modal-footer">
      </div role="modal content">
      <!--</form>-->
  </div role="modal-dialog">
</div role="dialog of signup">
<!--Closing of sign up modal -->
</form>
<script src="/static/bootstrap 3/jquery/jquery.form.js/">
</script>
```

**jquery code :**

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '#new_user_form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/librarysystem/registered/",
    data: {
      username: $('#username').val(),
      emailid: $('#emailid').val(),
      password: $('#password').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success: function() {
      alert("Registeration successfully.")
      $('#new_user_form').modal('hide');
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read your post. How readable is it? What could you do to make it easier for people to help you?

Comment: Your HTML is wrong, you have `<form>` inside the div, but `</form>` outside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hide the form not the modal. You have to use the `id` of the modal to hide the form.

Try to use this:

```
$('#signupmodal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: in input tag of submit button i included  this : onclose="showSuccessMessage();"   and blow it i wrote this script but it doesn't work why ?                                                                              <script type="text/javascript">
function showSuccessMessage() {
alert("Registeration successfully.");         }
</script>